# Create javascript dynamically

Tags: php, yii

I develop simple application, which generate external javascript file for inserting on site. Script generated with some data related to user settings. 
It's my first project on Yii.
I created Controller for getting user data from db.

```
public function actionScriptout($id)
{
    $this->layout= '//layouts/scriptout'; //empty layout
    $model=Scripts::model()->findByAttributes(array('code'=>$id));
    if($model===null)
        throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
    else {
        $params= json_decode($model->params);
        $script= $model->serviceScript($params->id, $params->service);

        echo $script .' '. $params->script;
    }
}
```

**UPDATED: Script renerated in** *$model->serviceScript($params->id, $params->service);*
I checked *$script* variable in debugger before function return value and all was fine: Variable contains all script.

```
public function serviceScript($id, $text) {
    $script= file_get_contents(Yii::app()->BasePath . '/../js/service.js');
    $script= str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $script);
    $script= str_replace('##id##', $id, $script);
    $out= CJSON::encode($text);
    $script= str_replace('##text_rep##', $out, $script);
    return $script;
}
```

In normal case, generated result

```
    document.getElementById('##id##').innerHTML = '88 88 888';
var stype= ['google.', 'yandex.', 'vk.', 'facebook.'];
var text_rep= ##text_rep##;
window.onload= function() {
    for (i=0; i<stype.length; i++) {
        if (document.referrer.search(stype[i]) != -1) {
            document.getElementById('##id##').innerHTML = text_rep[i];
        } else {
            document.getElementById('##id##').innerHTML = '88 88 888';
        }
    }
}
```

Script avalable on url http://domen.name/index.php?r=scripts/scriptout&id=153e1edd3e2b5e6.81264252

But it's output only this part

```
document.getElementById('footer').innerHTML = '88 88 888'; 
var stype= ['google.', 'yandex.', 'vk.', 'facebook.']; 
var text_rep= [null,"wdwdw",null,"dwd"]; 
window.onload= function() { for (i=0; i
```

What I need to do to properly output all script?

Comment: Not enought information: We need to see the code that actually generates the incorrect output, not just the code that calls the code that generates the output.

Comment: See you point, I update description. But I watched generated text value in debugger before it's actually has been printed on page and all was fine: variable contains full script, but in page you can see only part.
May be some .htaccess trick needed?

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem with adding line

```
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
```

to layout file.